# Cron job unable to execute non-root script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a script say:

```
[operations@dojo 2018-02-23--18-10-53 ~ $] ls -l cc_snapshot.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 operations users 6006 Feb 23 15:02 cc_snapshot.sh
```

/etc/cron.allow

```
operations
```

crontab -l

```
*/3 * * * * operations /home/operations/cc_snapshot.sh arg1 arg2 >> /var/log/cc_snapshot.log
```

However nothing gets printed in the /var/log/cc_snapshot.log.
If I remove the operations user from the cron I do see errors in /var/log/cc_snapshot.log as the script is not supposed to be executed as root user.

Any advise as to what I might be wrong here?

Comment: There are 11.5K questions asked about cron on this site :)

Comment: You don't have write permission in `/var/log`.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a file permission issue. `root` is the supper user in `Unix` environment and it can execute any script in that system. Hence second error message is coming from your script but not from shell. You script don't want it to be run by root. Check the user account whether it has proper access to the file location and proper permission to execute the script. These are the very common issues in `Unix` environment. Also check whether your user id is added to proper group or not.